# XCTest - Waiting for predicate fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to wait for a string to appear in the navbar during a UI test. When trying to set the expectation I get a "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1". What am I doing wrong here?

```
expectation(for: NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS 'Rent'"), 
    evaluatedWith: XCUIApplication().navigationBars.staticTexts, 
    handler: nil)
waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
```

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set? Remove it if you do.

Comment: No. There is no breakpoint set. Breakpoint 1.1 usually indicates some internal exception. Continuing from that point usually gives more info but it does not in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. You need an element not a query. So the code should be:

```
expectation(for: NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1"), 
  evaluatedWith: XCUIApplication().navigationBars.staticTexts.
  element(matching: NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS 'Rent'")), 
  handler: nil)
waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
```

Comment: Updated to improved matching as previous did not always match correctly